# #1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Tags: mysql

I have a serial no. column which is auto increment, but I want enrollment id. to be the primary key and MySQL is just not allowing me to do that. Is there any way around to do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can only define a column as `AUTO_INCREMENT` if it is a `PRIMARY KEY` and an `INT` <sup>(*not sure of this but BIGINT will work too*)</sup>. Since you want the `SerialNo` to be set as `AUTO_INCREMENT`, why not make it as `PRIMARY KEY` and the `EnrollmentID` as `UNIQUE`?

```
CREATE TABLE TableName
(
    SerialNo INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    EnrollmentID INT UNIQUE,
    -- other columns...
)
```

Comment: Well that makes sense. But then what is the whole purpose of a primary key, unique seems to be doing the same task.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you define your serial number column as `UNIQUE`.

Answer (score 1):

CREATE TABLE `tbl_login` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`first_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`last_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`gender` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`address` text NOT NULL,
`mobile_no` varchar(15) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;